# Problema a la hora de guardar row en DataSet usando ADO.net

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2017, ado.net, innodb

Os traigo otro problemilla que me surgió durante mi proyecto (que está casi acabado ya). Lo que este código se supone que debería hacer es crearme una fila "Artista" nueva, añadirla al dataset (en su datatable) y hacer update a la database.
Bien, está claro que algo me falta. Pero no sé qué. Lo siento por ser tan noob, de verdad que no soy capaz y llevo ya unas buenas horas dándome de bruces contra esto. Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Los campos de la tabla son: Name (Varchar),Genre(Varchar), Labels(Varchar) y RealName(Varchar) y en la clase Artist son los mismos, con String.

```
private void addToDataTable(DataTable d,Object objeto)
    {
        DataRow newRow;

        if (d.TableName.Equals("artists"))
        {
            Artist dbArtist = (Artist)objeto;

            newRow = ds.Tables["Artists"].NewRow();
            newRow[0] = dbArtist.Name.ToString();
            newRow[1] = dbArtist.Genre.ToString();
            newRow[2]=dbArtist.Labels.ToString();
            daArtists.Update(ds,"Artists");

        }
        else if (d.TableName.Equals("albums"))
        {
            newRow = ds.Tables["Albums"].NewRow();
        }
        else
        {
            //newRow = ds.Tables["Songs"].NewRow();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Así se agrega una nueva fila `ds.Tables["Artists"].Rows.Add(newRow);`

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar una nueva fila solo debes acceder a las filas de la tabla mediante `.Rows` y luego usar el método `.Add()` para agregar una nueva fila quedando algo similar a esto:

`ds.Tables["Artists"].Rows.Add(newRow);`

Entonces tu código debe quedar así:

```
private void addToDataTable(DataTable d,Object objeto)
{
    DataRow newRow;

    if (d.TableName.Equals("artists"))
    {
        Artist dbArtist = (Artist)objeto;

        newRow = ds.Tables["Artists"].NewRow();
        newRow[0] = dbArtist.Name.ToString();
        newRow[1] = dbArtist.Genre.ToString();
        newRow[2]=dbArtist.Labels.ToString();
        ds.Tables["Artists"].Rows.Add(newRow);
        daArtists.Update(ds, "Artists");
    }
    else if (d.TableName.Equals("albums"))
    {
        newRow = ds.Tables["Albums"].NewRow();
    }
    else
    {
        //newRow = ds.Tables["Songs"].NewRow();
    }
}
```

Para insertar en tu base de datos puedes recorrer las filas de tu `DataTable` e insertar de esta manera:

```
using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION_STRING"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tabla VALUES (@Name, @Genre, @Labels)", cnx))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", 0));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Genre", 0));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Labels", 0));
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["Artists"].Rows)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = row[0];
            cmd.Parameters["@Genre"].Value = row[1];
            cmd.Parameters["@Labels"].Value = row[2];
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Otra manera es enviando la tabla en una sola [consulta](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-from-c-sharp-to-sql).

Si lo que quieres es guardar el último registro puedes seleccionar la última fila utilizando `Linq` de esta manera:

```
using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION_STRING"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tabla VALUES (@Name, @Genre, @Labels)", cnx))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", 0));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Genre", 0));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Labels", 0));
        DataRow row = ds.Tables["Artists"].AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault();
        cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = row[0];
        cmd.Parameters["@Genre"].Value = row[1];
        cmd.Parameters["@Labels"].Value = row[2];
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Y entonces, una vez hecho esto, como hago para que esto se haga efectivo en la database? O sea, tengo que conectarme nuevamente pero y despues? Era para eso la linea fracasada de "update" jajaja

Comment: Pero para ingresar un registro en la base de datos no es necesario agregar una fila en tu aplicación con hacer una consulta tienes, ahora si quieres guardar la tabla completa la puedes enviar una sola [consulta](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-from-c-sharp-to-sql) o recorriendo todos los registros 1 a 1 y realizando una consulta a la base de datos por cada registro.

Comment: Ya te coloque como debes hacer para guardar en tu base de datos.

Comment: Ya vi, el problema es que yo necesito que sea usando el DataSet, no asi. Y es que se supone que con el comando Update ya funciona, pero no lo está haciendo...

Comment: Debería funcionar usando `daArtists.Update(ds, "Artists");` la verdad nunca lo he usado primera vez que lo veo, siempre hago mis consultas.